# What is the proper interpretation of the slope of the regression equation?

Tags: regression, self-study

Measured Wind Speed MWS
Cental Pressure CP

MWS= 955.27 - 0.897(CP)

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: it is from a course.

Comment: Thank you for adding the `[self-study]` tag. Please read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. We'll probably need some additional context for the question as well. At present, it seems to come from out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

When central pressure *increases* by one unit, measured win speed *decreases* $0.897$ units.

When central pressure *decreases* by one unit, measured wind speed *increases* by $0.897$ units.

Also notice that when central pressure is zero, measures wind speed is $955.27$ units.

More broadly, this regression equation predicts that central pressure will have a negative impact on measured wind speed. The less central pressure, the greater the wind speed.